# login to ubuntu 15.1 help

Tags: upgrade

Linux newbie here.  I have been using Zorin 9 for awhile, and overnight had my system upgrade to Ubuntu 15.1.   I let it load, and this morning it is asking for a login and password, which I did not set.  How does one get into the system to discover or change the login and password?

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+ Alt+F1 to enter the terminal and login with your username and hit enter if you haven't given a password.